# Find the tag name in PhpStorm color scheme

Tags: phpstorm

As you see there is a white line in the image, how could I change that to red and what tag name I should search for?

[image: phpstorm_color_scheme]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of this line in `Color Scheme > General` section, under `Editor > Guides > Indent guide`.